# The acceleration of circulation motion

Tags: kinematics, vectors, differentiation

We know that in circular motion the position vector  is $r\hat{r}$. Then the velocity is the time derivative of it. So it gives $$dv/dt = r d\hat{r}/dt + \frac{dr}{dt} .\hat{r}.$$ now I can't understand why $dr/dt$ isn't zero.  The $r$ or radii isn't changing throughout the circle. So should the velocity be only $rd\hat{r}/dt$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying that the position is $r\hat r$ does not only describe circular motion. This is just a general position vector.

Therefore, your time derivative is just a general velocity vector. The first term represents velocity tangent to the position vector, the second parallel to it. Therefore, if you are undergoing circular motion, the second term is $0$.

Based on your comments, I think I see your issue. You are thinking "I see $r\hat r$ is used in the case of circular motion, so it only describes circular motion". The correct way to see it is "$r\hat r$ is always true, so I can apply it to circular motion."

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed right to say that the term $\frac{dr}{dt}$ is *zero*. Indeed the velocity vector is given just by $r\frac{d\hat{r}}{dt}$.

You can see why this is true too if you consider the dot product of the velocity vector and the radius vector. Consider the displacement or position vector to be $r\hat{r}=r(\cos(\omega t)i+sin(\omega t)j$.

Now we know the derivative is $r\frac{d\hat{r}}{dt}$, which is equal to the derivative of the displacement vector with $r$ as constant, you get: 
$$r\frac{d\hat{r}}{dt}=$r(-\sin(\omega t)i+cos(\omega t)j$$
Now if you take the dot product of the two vectors you should get zero as is true in circular motion, that is the velocity vector is *perpendicular* to the radius vector. It is indeed true as the dot product yields :
$$(-\sin(\omega t)cos(\omega t) + \sin(\omega t)cos(\omega t))=0$$
As was to be shown.